# GoJS display shape on condition

Tags: javascript, gojs

How do I display a go.Shape based on a condition (specifically a variable's value)?

```
go$(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
{ height: diagram.width, strokeWidth: 0.5 },
new go.Binding("fill", "color"),
new go.Binding("width", "span", function (w) { return ScaleSegmentWidth(w); })
```

For example I don't want to display this shape if "span" is 0.

Comment: Use templateMaps http://gojs.net/latest/intro/templateMaps.html

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `data.span` is a number:

```
new go.Binding("visible", "span", function(span) { return span !== 0; })
```

By the way, a minor improvement might be possible in your other binding, if it takes only one argument:

```
new go.Binding("width", "span", ScaleSegmentWidth)
```